# How could I rewrite the sentence in active voice?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, passive-voice, active-voice

I have a passive voice as follows:

> The algorithm is naturally designed for texture classification.

It is a passive voice. Could I rewrite the above sentence in active voice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to rewrite the sentence in the active voice, you need a subject, such as the name of the researcher(s) or developer(s) who developed the algorithm, or something vaguer, such as "Researchers". This would result in something like:

- [Professor] John Doe designed the algorithm for texture classification.
- Researchers designed the algorithm for texture classification.

Two issues become apparent in this type of paraphrase:

- Is/are the designer/designers of the algorithm so important in the context of your text that they need to be mentioned?
- How do you reword "naturally" so it makes sense in an active sentence? In order to know this, it would be good to know *why* the algorithm is claimed to be "naturally designed" for its purpose.

Making a few assumptions about "naturally", the following paraphrases are possible:

- [Professor] John Doe designed the algorithm specifically for the purpose of texture classification.
- [Professor] John Doe designed the algorithm so it would be a good fit for texture classification.

Other paraphrases would be possible, depending on the intent of "naturally".

However, I would like to point out that the passive voice does not need to be avoided at all costs. Depending on the context, the original sentence may be a better choice than one that uses the active voice. This [article from Biomedical Editor](http://www.biomedicaleditor.com/passive-voice.html) describes a few situations when the passive voice is the better choice.

Comment: Great job. Thank you. If I do not know the object (Prof). Can I use the name of an algorithm? For example, the K-means algorithm specifically designed for the purpose of texture classification.

Comment: @user8430 If you want to mention the algorithm, the result would be: "The K-means algorithm is/was specifically designed for the purpose of texture classification." ([K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) has a long history.)